# Extract only certain types of files from folder

Tags: php

I'm a php newbie. 
I need to extract from a folder, all images. jpg available.
I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work

```
$type = 'jpg';

   $pics = opendir('admin/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/');
        $result = glob($pics.'*.'.$type);
           while ($filename = readdir($result)){
            if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {

                $path = 'admin/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/'.$filename;
                $image = 'admin/upload/server/php/files/'.$filename; 
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path);
                $path = 'http://localhost/site/'.$path;
                $image = 'http://localhost/site/'.$image;
```

Could someone help me to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting, and define "doesn't work". [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is your friend and so is your HTML source.

Comment: Dude, you're just mixing different approaches.  You don't need opendir(), readdir() and that if, etc with glob()!  Just foreach() over the $result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `glob()` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
foreach (glob("admin/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/*.jpg") as $filename) {
  $path = 'admin/upload/server/php/files/thumbnail/'. basename($filename);
  $image = 'admin/upload/server/php/files/'. basename($filename);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This works, but the problem now is that $ filename contains the path to the folder files / thumbnail. How do I get:
$path = 'files / thumbnail';
$image = 'files /';

Comment: I posted the solution.  Why accept what doesn't work?  Need to use basename()

Comment: Yes, thank you,  i used and solved with basename ()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's in $pics so I used basename.  Also, you are redefining $path and $image:

```
$type = 'jpg';
$result = array_map('basename', glob($pics.'*.'.$type));

foreach($result as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
    //etc...
}
```